# Java Virtual Machine programmed in Java language?

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any java virtual machine implemented in Java language utterly?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you need another JVM to run that JVM in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jikes RVM](http://jikesrvm.org/) and [Maxine](http://labs.oracle.com/projects/maxine/) are JVMs almost entirely written in Java.